# QEMU Boot Error : "Swapper used greatest stack depth"

Tags: kernel, boot, qemu

I have compiled 3.7.3 Kernel for x86_64 and created a root file system with the aid of busybox.

When i try to boot the system with QEMU, like this :

```
$qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -initrd rootfs.img.gz
```

It gives the following error:

[image: error]

I am not sure if i should provide some more details like rootfs tree or kernel config.

Comment: "xxx used greatest stack depth" is not an error, it's a debug message that you can safely ignore. The actual error is cut off from your screenshot, it should be above the registers' dump.

Answer (score 0):

When use initrd ramdisk ,you must  compile the linux kernel below...

General Setup –> Initial RAM filesystem and RAM disk support

Device Drivers –> Block Devices –> RAM block device support